# error when trying to retrieve data within a date range

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to retrieve data within a date range but get the following error

```
The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value
```

this is tghe basic sql query

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE date BETWEEN '19/12/2012' AND '1/17/2013'
GO
```

how can I rectify this error

Comment: Try to use a dateformat that will not be confused by locale settings. Use `yyyymmdd`. `BETWEEN '20121219' AND '20130117'`

Comment: Seems even the question is confused about date formats, first date is dd/mm/yy, second mm/dd/yy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using strings to represent datetime values leads to this kind of situation

```
SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE date BETWEEN Convert(smalldatetime, '19/12/2012', 105) AND Convert(smalldatetime, '1/17/2013', 101)
GO
```

But, I should ask you. Why do you use two different dateformats for the same query?

[See the Convert function on T-SQL here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) for an explanation and possible values for the final 101 parameter

Comment: `101` should probably be `103` in the first convert... but seems to be reversed on the second.

Comment: Strange, I noticed a bit of confusion here 19/12/2012 is dd/MM/yyyy and 1/17/2013 is mm/dd/yyyy.